# Oracle Getting latest value from the other table

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have two tables, table1 contains old values and table2 contains latest values, I want to show latest value in table1 but I do not have anything which tells me this is the latest value in table2.
for example
Table1

```
CID-----PID-----RID  
CT1-----C-------R1  
CT2-----C-------R2    
CT3-----C-------R3   
CT4-----C-------R4
```

Table2

```
CID-----PID----RID      
CT1-----A-------R1  
CT1-----C-------R11  
CT2-----C-------R2    
CT3-----A-------R3   
CT4-----A-------R4
```

The condition is I have to give priority to value C in case both values (A and C) exist also it's RID changes so need to get that also in output table, for the same CID and for unique value I will simple replace it in table1 from table2,  so output will be like this

Table3

```
CID-----PID----RID   
CT1-----C-------R11  
CT2-----C-------R2    
CT3-----A-------R3   
CT4-----A-------R4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be missing something, but isn't this simply:

```
select cid, max(pid)
from table2
group by cid;
```

If you want whole records, use a ranking with `ROW_NUMBER` instead:

```
select cid, pid, rid
from
(
  select cid, pid, rid, row_number() over (partition by cid order by pid desc) as rn
  from table2
)
where rn = 1;
```

You can also use case expressions for ranking, e.g.:

```
(partition by cid order by case pid when 'C' then 1 when 'A' then 2 else 3 end) as rn
```

---

**UPDATE:** Now that you've finally explained what you are after ...

You want more or less the second query I gave you above. Only that you want data from both tables, which you can get with `UNION ALL`. You can easily give each row a rank on the way:

- table2 PIM C => rank #1
- table2 PIM A => rank #2
- table1 rank #3

Then again take the row with the best rank:

```
select cid, pid, rid
from
(
  select cid, pid, rid, row_number() over (partition by cid order by rnk) as rn
  from
  (
    select cid, pid, rid, case when pid = 'C' then 1 else 2 end as rnk from table2
    union
    select cid, pid, rid, 3 as rnk from table1
  )
)
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: it is not, In my actual table I may have PID values as CED and ADD, but actually it is a good idea I can use this somewhere else.

Comment: I've updated my answer according to your edited request. I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: There *are* already two columns PID and RID in your table1. So far it seems you have table1 which you don't need actually and table2 which contains the real data. So delete (i.e. drop) table1 and you are fine, I would say. I don't know why you would want to *update* table1 instead. That would mean to store data redundantly which you shouldn't. Or is table2 just a temporary thing you want to delete afterwards?

Comment: I still don't get it. In your sample data you get all values needed from table2. So you can ignore table1 completely. There is no need to update anything because you can get the data you want to see with a simple select as shown anytime you want.

Comment: I don't understand that either. When you want to look up CT1, you use my second query and get PID = C, RID = R11. What else do you need?

Comment: Ah, this is new information that you completely forgot to tell us. So to summarize what I think I understand: 1. There can be zero to one record for C1 in table1. 2. There can be zero, one, or many records for C1 in table2. 3. There exist different PID values (A, C, CED, ADD, and maybe more). 4. If there is a PID A or PID C record in table2 for C1, it has precedence over a C1 record in table1 if such exists, no matter what PID in table1. 5. A PID C record in table2 has precedence over a PID A record in table2. 6. I don't know how you'd want a PID CED or PID ADD record in table2 to be treated.

Comment: thanks, yes, everything is correct, just remove point 6 and one more thing there could only be zero, one or two values in table2 for every c1 in table1, for simplicity just say A and C.

Comment: I've added a solution to my answer. So I found out what you were really asking, provided an algorithm and wrote the query. Next time there should be more effort on your side.

Comment: thanks, I'm getting the result I need with your answers, but I have I more need from your query one, this is only for table2, can I get  only CID's whose PID has changed from A to C or whose PID was only A. So from table2 I'll get record for CT1, CT3 and CT4 (here  table1 in not involved)

Comment: Use a `HAVING` clause. I leave this as an exercise for you.